# Android Spinner Adapter Not working

Tags: android, android-spinner

In Android, I want to create spinner and parse data from url and inject it in my spinner, For Info: I have menu in all activities and tabs in Home Activity, So I create Base class Activity for common Menu Please If you have enhancement to my code please inform me Main Issue: Spinner Not show my data and give me Exception error with Set Adapter

Here Base Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected LinearLayout fulllayout;
    protected FrameLayout actContent;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        //For make Menu RTL
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        fulllayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);    
        actContent = (FrameLayout) fulllayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content);    
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);

        super.setContentView(fulllayout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here Home Activity:

```
package com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Adapters.CityAdapter;
import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Beans.CityBeans;
import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.customviews.WrapContentViewPager;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class Home extends BaseActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */    

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private TextView tap1, tap2;
    private String cityUrl = "http://arabnewtech.org/zoodre/public/api/locations/city/3";
    private Spinner citySpinner;
    public  ArrayList<CityBeans> cityBeansList = new ArrayList<CityBeans>();
    TextView output = null;
    CityAdapter adapter;
    Home activity = null;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private WrapContentViewPager mViewPager;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (WrapContentViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // Create Tabs Handelation
        tabsHandel();

        // Initialize Views
        initViews();

        // City Spinner
        setListData();    

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void initViews() {
        activity = this;
        citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityID);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);   
    }
     public void setListData() {

    // Now I have taken static values by loop.
    // For further inhancement we can take data by webservice / json / xml;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        final CityBeans sched = new CityBeans();

        /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
        sched.setId("id " + i);
        sched.setName("Name" + i );

        /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
        cityBeansList.add(sched);
    }

          /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
        adapter = new CityAdapter(activity, R.layout.spinner_rows, cityBeansList);
        // Set adapter to spinner
        citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Listener called when spinner item selected
        citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Get selected row data to show on screen
                String Company = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();
                String CompanyUrl = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub)).getText().toString();

                String OutputMsg = "Selected Company : \n\n" + Company + "\n" + CompanyUrl;
                output.setText(OutputMsg);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(), OutputMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }
        });
}


    public void tabsHandel() {
        tap1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap1);
        tap2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap2);

        tap1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        tap2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client2, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Home Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client2, viewAction);
        client2.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            // textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Case 0";
                case 1:
                    return "Case 1";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here City Beans:

```
package com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by abozaid on 27/09/16.
 */
public class CityBeans implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here City Adapter:

```
package com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Adapters;

/**
 * Created by abozaid on 28/09/16.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Beans.CityBeans;
import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home;
import com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.R;

public class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    CityBeans tempValues=null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CityAdapter(
            Home activitySpinner,
            int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList objects
    )
    {
        super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = activitySpinner;
        data     = objects;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("Iammmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","Herrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);

        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (CityBeans) data.get(position);

        TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
        TextView sub          = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);

        if(position==0){
            // Default selected Spinner item
            label.setText("Please select Name");
            sub.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            // Set values for spinner each row
            label.setText(tempValues.getId());
            sub.setText(tempValues.getName());

        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Here Fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/cityID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/zoneID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorYellow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:text="بحث"/>    

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/output" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here Spinner_Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip"
    >
    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/company"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:text="sfsdf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorYellow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:text="sfsf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/company"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Log Cat Out put:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate/com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home.setListData(Home.java:123)
                                                                                     at com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home.onCreate(Home.java:89)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the logcat output

Comment: _italic_  I Added it

Comment: can you debug and check what is the content of this line ```JSONArray jo_result = jo.getJSONArray("result");```

Comment: i make debug already and its have Json Array, I change code to simple code for more help

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the issue after replicating your code. In your code's `public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method...

You are inflating

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, parent, false);
```

But it has to be

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
```

Comment: You are right this is issue but i replaced it for test something and return it to spinner_row again and same exception, i feel the problem with inheritance from base activity because i tried this code with clean project and working fine

Comment: if you still have issue, upload it to github and give me the link. i will see what is wrong

Comment: Okey, Please check this link
[github link](https://gist.github.com/Mohammed2050/7e04d8f76772c2dd53f0c2d06df3e7f9)

Comment: i meant complete project that i can run out of the box. possible?

Comment: Sorry its big file 33M, Can we use team viewer if possible?